# Is it possible to create 1:1 relationship with out using foreign key in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to create 2 table with 1:1 relationship. Is it possible to create 1:1 relationship without using foreign key?

Comment: Since standard SQL precludes any DML that affects more than a single table, how would you expect that any such tables in a 1:1 relationship could be populated?

Comment: Why not have the data in one table. Enforcing 1:1 is not possible, as one must occur before the other, and the other may not not occurr

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, my colleagues are doing discussion about this thing that for 1:1 relationship foreign key is not necessary. I am curious about it that's why i asked this question

Comment: You _could_ do it with triggers (and without foreign key constraints). But what's the point?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you don't need a single DML to populate such a table.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a number of ways to do this.

1. If you have one row in each table you have a 1:1 relationship
2. If you have a field in one table that maps to one field in some derivative way, you have a 1:1 relationship.  For example, if you have telephone numbers and another table for area codes, you could assume that each telephone number will match one area code and could join on a substring.

The second is sort of like a foreign key but not quite.